# Question involving the homomorphism theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $A$ be a ring and $f:A \to A$ a surjective homomorphism. If $A/\ker f \cong A$ then is $f$ injective??

I know how to prove the other direction, but this one I don't know how to solve. Do you have any idea? Of course, if $A$ is finite then the exercise is trivial.

Comment: A ring $A$ for which every surjective morphism $f\colon A\to A$ must in fact be an isomorphism (i.e., $f$ is injective) is called a *Hopfian ring* (more generally, you have the notion of [Hopfian object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_object) ). Finite rings are Hopfian, but as José Carlos Santos shows, not every infinite ring is Hopfian.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not true. Take $A=\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\times\cdots$ and $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots)$. Then $\ker f=\Bbb Z\times\{0\}\times\{0\}\times\cdots$, and $A/\ker f\simeq A$.

Comment: Is the isomorphism $g:A\simeq A/\ker f$ given by $g(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=\Bbb Z\times\{x_2\}\times\{x_3\}\times\ldots$?

Comment: No, it's$$f\bigl((x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)+\ker f)=(x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots).$$

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the other direction.

Comment: Sure! Sorry about that. It's$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)+\ker f.$$

Comment: Oh, you're right. Mine didn't move the $x_1$ to the right, it just got rid of it, so it wasn't injective. Thanks.